# increment a variable like */2.4.7 via python

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to increase the last int in a variable by one, and have gotten stuck on how to do this correctly.

```
version = tree.find('.//BranchSpec/name').text;

sprint = int(version.split(".")[2])
sprint = sprint + 1 
newversion = version.split(".")[0] , version.split(".")[1], sprint # output ('*/2', '4', 8)
```

I want the output to be `*/2.4.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split off the last part only, [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) is the fastest way to do that:

```
prefix, _, sprint = version.rpartition('.')
newversion = '{}.{}'.format(prefix, int(sprint) + 1)
```

Partitioning gives us the prefix as well, its easier just to reuse that when forming the new version again.

You could also do it with [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and a limit:

```
prefix, sprint = version.rsplit('.', 1)  # split just once
newversion = '{}.{}'.format(prefix, int(sprint) + 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> version = '*/2.4.7'
>>> prefix, _, sprint = version.rpartition('.')
>>> '{}.{}'.format(prefix, int(sprint) + 1)
'*/2.4.8'
>>> prefix, sprint = version.rsplit('.', 1)  # split just once
>>> '{}.{}'.format(prefix, int(sprint) + 1)
'*/2.4.8'
```